# React Native Android Auto ANR API: GET_APP_VERSION Error

Tags: react-native, android-anr-dialog, android-auto

Iam trying to implement the library react-native-android-auto.
Since its no longer maintained I have forked and done some modifications on the repo my self.
Got everything to compile and run and the android app itself works, except the android auto app.

When I try to open the AA app I get the error ANR API: GET*_*APP_VERSION error.

Anyone else got this error or can point me in the correct direction?

For clarification, Iam testing it on the desktop head unit.

[image]

I have tried everything, changed my android manifest to see if I can get it to work. Have also tried logcat without any luck.